# Simple shader that scales UI image from the center

Tags: unity, shaders, gui, vertex-shader

I'm having trouble making a (vertex) shader that scales **UI images** from the center.

I can scale the image, but the image doesn't stay centered.

[Here is a project showing the problem](https://github.com/trenthm/Image-Scale-Shader)

[Here is a direct link to the shader I'm working on](https://github.com/trenthm/Image-Scale-Shader/blob/master/Assets/Fast-Default-Scaled.shader)

**How can I make it scale from the center?**

*See how the basketballs do not stay centered in their original rects in the below image*

[image: See how the basketballs do not stay centered in their original rects]
[image: Here is some extra info]

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this in a shader, rather than simply scaling the UI Image GameObject itself via its RectTransform?

Comment: Of course. https://forum.unity.com/threads/need-help-with-scaling-vertex-positions-in-shader.592804/#post-4348915

Comment: Applying a fractional scale to a UI sprite is not recommended, as it leads to a slight blurring from bilinear filtering. Would you be open to solutions to get the size you want (without mipmapping artifacts) where those solutions do not involve scaling in the shader? If so, I'd recommend editing your post to talk about the root problem you're trying to solve, rather than your attempted solution.

Comment: I noticed the slight blurring, and was choosing that over the "smudged" edges caused by mipmaps. Maybe I should make a more fundamental post, though. As for fractional scaling, doesn't something like this already happen when sprites are rendered in general?

Comment: There's no reason you should have to accept either of these artifacts if you're displaying your asset at a fixed known resolution.

Comment: I'd love to not use mipmaps at all, since they cause artifacts and blurriness. Not sure how to control resolution across mobile devices though... really appreciate your feedback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91429/discussion-between-tread-and-dmgregory).